# Terms in Android MEMINFO in dumpsys

Tags: android, linux

I'm working with android memory usage and can someone help me with understanding the terms used here. It is not clearly explained in android helper [See Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys)

Im more focused on how PSS Total & PSS Clean are calculated? Terms Stack, Ashmem, Gfx dev in the context of memory usage.

Meminfo Snapshot [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKCJ5.png)

Comment: You need to list the terms you are having trouble with.

Comment: How PSS Clean is calculated?  Terms Stack, Ashmem, Gfx dev in the context of memory usage.

Comment: Please add the information too your question by clicking *Edit*. Then delete the comment by clicking *X* next to it.